# Centring a variety of images to a div

Tags: css, image, html

I have a div, say 200px by 200px. I am making a slideshow of images, all of different sizes. I want the pictures to be all centered on the div, but only 200 by 200 of them visible. So if a picture is larger, only a portion of it is shown.

How do I do that?

Thanks
Kousha

Comment: You will have to use HTML, CSS and Javascript (possibly jQuery). I gave you all you will need to do that, according to what have you showed. Please, post some of your code. We are not here to code for free. We are here to help people with their codes and solve some doubts.

Comment: Were any [answers provided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11182674/144665) useful?

Answer (score 0):

User `overflow: hidden;` style on the div.

Comment: ? "... pictures to be all centered on the div ..."

Comment: @iambriansreed - wow, really, a -1? how do you know he is not using an `<img>` tag inside the div, or just anything else really, he hasn't posted any actual code - please remove the downvote, or I'll find something to nitpick with your answer...

Comment: The purpose of voting is to push good content to the top and bad content to the bottom. If my answer is indeed erroneous or missing part of the solution let me know and I will change my answer.

Comment: @iambriansreed - as I said, nothing in my answer is erroneous, or missing for that matter - because I don't know how he inserts images on the page... but as you wish

Comment: You made a good point about him using an img tag but you didn't even include that in your answer.

Comment: This is not a discussion forum. Please, ask in the comments before posting. Some people like to downvote at first sight, but its not personal, its just the way this site works.

Comment: @rcdmk Some people down vote out of spite, even going as far as to admitting it in the comments of their own answer.

Comment: @rcdmk downvoting a helpful answer, be it that way only partly or not, is **not** how this site **should** work...

Answer (score -1):

The following will center all images. Images greater than the width and height of the div will be cropped.

In your stylesheet:

```
div {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff center center no-repeat;
}
```

In your HTML:

```
<div style="background-image: url('url_of_image.jpg')"></div>
```

Comment: ? "I want the **pictures**..." -1 because you haven't taken that into account, also you should show him **how** to make a slideshow... and how to insert a div on the page too, for good measure